# Music not playing when user logged in with Deezer SDK for Android

Tags: android, deezer

I am using the Deezer Android SDK (0.10.16) and I try to play songs with the PlaylistPlayer.
I have a weird problem even though I use it in the most basic way :

```
mPlaylistPlayer = new PlaylistPlayer(getActivity().getApplication(), mDeezerConnect,
                    new WifiAndMobileNetworkStateChecker());
mPlaylistPlayer.playPlaylist(451051205);
```

This code doesn't play anything when the user is logged. I have no error or warning, the music just doesn't start. (the volume controls change the phone volume and not the media volume when I use them in this case, so I am sure no media is launched).

The weird thing is : when the user is not logged in -and the DeezerConnect created but not authorized yet-, or logs and then logs out, the songs are played (for 30 seconds each).

I did this :

In my Activity

```
public class DrawerActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
...
DeezerConnect deezerConnect = null;
PlaylistPlayer mPlaylistPlayer = null;
...
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    deezerConnect = new DeezerConnect(this, applicationID);
    ...
}

@Override
public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) { 
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    //The user will connect here
    if(position==2){
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container, AccountsFragment.newInstance(deezerConnect))
                .commit();
    }
}
```

The user connects in my AccountsFragments

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if(v == deezerConnectBtn){
        if(!mDeezerConnect.isSessionValid())
            mDeezerConnect.authorize(getActivity(), DrawerActivity.permissions, mDeezerDialogListener);
        else {
            mDeezerConnect.logout(getActivity());

            deezerLoginTxt.setText("You're not connected");
        }
    }
}
```

This works, i can fetch user info, go back to another fragment and still get the Boolean.toString(deezerConnect.isSessionValid())==true.

But when I then launch a player from this activity, it is in PLAYING state when I launch it with Boolean.toString(deezerConnect.isSessionValid())==false, and STOPPED when Boolean.toString(deezerConnect.isSessionValid())==true

I launch the player like this (here in my Activity) :

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container, PlayerFragment.newInstance(locationId, playlistId, deezerConnect, mPlaylistPlayer))
                .commit();
```

And then in my PlayerFragment :

```
private static PlaylistPlayer mPlaylistPlayer;
private static DeezerConnect mDeezerConnect;

@Override
public static PlayerFragment newInstance(String locationId, String playlistId, DeezerConnect deezerConnect, PlaylistPlayer playlistPlayer) {
    PlayerFragment fragment = new PlayerFragment();
    ...
    mPlaylistPlayer = playlistPlayer;
    mDeezerConnect = deezerConnect;
}
...
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if(mPlaylistPlayer==null){
        try {
            mPlaylistPlayer = new PlaylistPlayer(getActivity().getApplication(), mDeezerConnect,
                    new WifiAndMobileNetworkStateChecker());
            mPlaylistPlayer.playPlaylist(mPlaylistId);

            mListener.onFragmentInteraction(mPlaylistPlayer);
        } catch (TooManyPlayersExceptions tooManyPlayersExceptions) {
            tooManyPlayersExceptions.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "toomanyplayers", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch (DeezerError deezerError) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "deezerError", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            deezerError.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The passing of arguments to the last fragment is kind of dirty, but it works very well when I am not connected, and when I am, the player state is always STOPPED.

Comment: Could you paste the whole process you're  going through (from the moment the user logs in to the moment you try and play the playlist)

Comment: Do you create the PlaylistPlayer before or after login in ?

Comment: It depends on how you use the app, so I can test both cases. But when I create it before the login, the music plays, when I do it after, the music doesn't. I thought the opposite should be happening.

Comment: If you create it before, it fallbacks to the cse were there is no user logged, and it plays the 30s previews. If you add a PlayerErrorListener on the PlaylistPlayer do you have any error triggered ?

Comment: Sorry I missed that. It returns a com.deezer.sdk.player.exception.InvalidStreamTokenException: Invalid Stream Token
when the user is logged in. Doesn't return any error when he is not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not really a solution, but I found out that the problem only occured with emulators (I am using Genymotion), and not real devices.
I still don't know why, but at least the music plays.